# Disable node highlighting in ILPlotCube?

Tags: plot, ilnumerics

I create a ILPlotCube to render a 3D array in TwoDMode. I then add several lines in the scene.
It appears that when the mouse is located over a node, this node is highlighted in purple and its original color is removed.

Is this behaviour expected? If yes, how can I disable it?

For info, I'm running a notebook with dual graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 + GeForce GT 650M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All drawable nodes are marked by default when the mouse is over them. In order to disable this behavior, set the 'Markable' property to false:

```
var lines = new ILLines() {
   Markable = false
}; 
scene.Camera.Add(lines);
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. However, for ILSurface objects it seems ILSurface.Markable has no effect. Indeed, I had to set ILSurface.Fill.Markable and ILSurface.Wireframe.Markable to false individually. Is this expected?

Comment: Right. ILSurface is a group node. Groups still provide the Markable property for more flexibility. Custom solutions may use it. ILSurface currently does not.